# Pandas Bug?: Mean of an grouped-by int64 column stays as int64 in some circumstances

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am finding a very strange (IMHO) behaviour with some data loaded into pandas from a CSV file. To protect the innocent, let's state that the `DataFrame` is in the variable `homes` and, among others, has the columns below:

```
In [143]: homes[['zipcode', 'sqft', 'price']].dtypes
Out[143]:
zipcode     int64
sqft        int64
price       int64
dtype: object
```

To get the average price in each zipcode, I tried:

```
In [146]: homes.groupby('zipcode')[['price']].mean().head(n=5)
Out[146]:
           price
zipcode
28001     280804
28002     234284
28003     294111
28004    1355927
28005     810164
```

Strangely enough, the price mean is an int64 as shown by:

```
In [147]: homes.groupby('zipcode')[['price']].mean().dtypes
Out[147]:
price    int64
dtype: object
```

I am not able to imagine any technical reason why the mean of some ints is not promoted to float. Even more, just adding another column, makes the price to become a float64 
as I expected it to be all the time:

```
In [148]: homes.groupby('zipcode')[['price', 'sqft']].mean().dtypes
Out[148]:
price       float64
sqft        float64
dtype: object

                  price          sqft
zipcode
28001     280804.690608  14937.450276
28002     234284.035176   7517.633166
28003     294111.278571  10603.096429
28004    1355927.097792  13104.220820
28005     810164.880952  19928.785714
```

To ensure I was not missing something very obvious, I created another very simple `DataFrame` (`df`) but, with this one, this behaviour is not appearing:

```
In [161]: df[['J','K']].dtypes
Out[161]:
J    int64
K    int64
dtype: object

In [164]: df[['J','K']].head(n=10)
Out[164]:
   J   K
0  0  -9
1  0 -14
2  0   8
3  0 -11
4  0  -7
5 -1   7
6  0   2
7  0   0
8  0   5
9  0   3

In [165]: df.groupby('J')[['K']].mean()
Out[165]:
           K
J
-2 -2.333333
-1  0.466667
 0 -1.030303
 1 -1.750000
 2 -3.000000
```

Please, note that with a single column, K:int64, grouped by J, another int64, the mean is directly a float. The `homes` `DataFrame` was read from
a supplied CSV file, the `df` one has been created in pandas, written into a CSV and then read back.

Last but not least, I am using pandas 0.16.2.

Comment: Do you get a different result with: `homes.groupby('zipcode')['price'].mean().head(n=5)`? (Note single vs. double brackets around `price`.

Comment: I am getting the same result

    In [171]: homes.groupby('zipcode')['price'].mean().head(n=5)
    Out[171]:
    zipcode
    98001     280804
    98002     234284
    98003     294111
    98004    1355927
    98005     810164
    Name: price, dtype: int64

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.  You may want to report it. https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

Comment: Can you post some sample data?  E.g., is it possible there's only price per zipcode?  In general, `pandas` will compute the mean as a float64, but convert back to an int64 only if it's possible to do so without losing information.

Comment: I guess pandas must be doing floor (integer) division instead of floating point division?  (But why it's doing that, I couldn't guess.)  I.e. in python 2.x, 3/2 = 1.  This changed in python 3, so I'm guessing you are using python 2?  Anyway, it would be good if you can come up with a minimal complete verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Closest issue I can find is this:  https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/10172  I'm not sure this is related, but it does mention some behavior in numpy 1.8 vs 1.9, so you might update numpy to 1.9 if you haven't already and see if that helps.  Either way, you might want to edit your post to mention your python and numpy versions.

Comment: Hi, I am using numpy 1.9.3. Sorry for not detailing this before. I am not sure this is related.

Comment: @JohnE, I have been working with this a little bit more and there is a chance you were right. Or, at least, on the right track. I have been able to create a mcve without using the original data (which I am not sure I was authorized to share).

Comment: @Alexander, I am going to report it as a bug (tentatively).

Comment: @chrisb, I was not sure I can post the original data (a sample) but I have worked out a way to reproduce the problem. I will post it in the bug report to pandas developers and point to it from here.

Comment: Just posted a bug report to the pandas team.
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11199
If, it is accepted, I will create an answer pointing to it.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by some of you in the comments, this is a bug in pandas. I have just reported it [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11199).

As of now, it has been accepted by the pandas team.

Thanks